# Why does the head() function not work with data frames that include Dates in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, lubridate

I have been trying to use the head() function with a dataframe that includes a column of the Date class in RMarkdown. I have found that if I run the following code in an R script, the heads of both df_1 and df_2 will print to the console. If, however, I run it in an RMarkdown code chunk, only the head of df_1 will print. Does anyone know why?

```
library(lubridate)

vec1 <- c(1:10)
string_vec2 <- "2018-07-07"
df_1 <- merge(vec1, string_vec2)
head(df_1)



date_vec2 <- ymd("2018-07-07")
df_2 <- merge(vec1, date_vec2)
head(df_2)
```

Comment: One of those is a character value, the other is a Date. Furthermore, there is no `vec2`

Comment: you don't have `vec2` defined. Is that supposed to be `date_vec2`? Are you sure only the head of `df_1` is printed? and not the head of `df_2`?

Comment: Apologies for the typo I just changed it and it still doesn't run.

Comment: Why should a `merge` of a sequence of numbers and a single character value give anything useful? You are _not_ creating a dataframe.  Look up the documentation for `merge` and run the examples. This appears to have nothing to do with either `lubridate` or `Rmarkdown`.